# How to Hide Foundation flash message?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash, zurb-foundation

I'm really confused as to how to hide a flash message in my rails app. I've read the documentation but I'm not sure how to do this correctly. I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

For my app, I have a flash message/alert for submitting videos/comments/sign_in,sign_up etc. etc. Below is the flash code in my application.html.erb file:

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
    <% if msg.is_a?(String) %>
      <div data-alert class="alert-box <%= name.to_s == 'notice' ? 'success' : 'alert'    
        n%>">
        <%= content_tag :div, msg %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

The part that I get confused is the jquery part. On Foundation, the docs say that to customize it you need these three files:

```
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.alert.js"></script>
```

I thought these files were already in foundation. Do I need to create them under my app/assets/javascripts/ directory? Also, why would I need to add these at the bottom of my application file? I thought this tag 
    `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>` does it for me? It should because of the * require tree right?

I'm just confused about what goes where and what needs to go in what? For example, to hide the flash messages, where would I put this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.alert-box alert').fadeOut(1000);
  $('.alert-box success').fadeOut(1000);
});
```

Does this go in the foundation.alert.js file,the foundation.js file, or the vendor/jquery.js file or somewhere completely different. Some help would be nice.So confused.......

Answer (score 0):

I needed similar functionality once in which I had to fade out the flash message only on one specific page.

I created a separate JS file and required it in `application.js`.

I think to apply it to all the flash messages you need to put it in `foundation.alert.js`

Comment: Thanks the reply Babar. Just to clarify, your'e saying I create a foundation.alert.js file in the javascript tree along with the application.js and then require it? Just to ask doesn't the require tree part in the application.js require the files in the javascript directory?

Comment: Mine was misbehaving so I removed the require tree, it was loading the files in s sequence that most of the JS required in application stopped working, it was over ridden, but since you will be overriding the whole foundation.alert.js you will not run into such problems, require tree is the way to go, I was just telling how I tackled my scenario where I needed flash message disappearance on one particular page,  hope this explains it

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
setTimeout(function() { $(".alert-box a.close").trigger("click.fndtn.alert"); }, 1000);
```